# I can not get specific values in this return json

Tags: php, json, get

the following code is returning me a json, I would like to get the values Lat and Long, but I can not in any way, I have already tried several forms (using other tutorials of the site), can anyone help me?

```
<?php


  $data = array('email'=>'XXXUSERXXX','password'=>'XXXPASSXXX');
  $data2 = json_encode($data);
$headers = [
    'x-api-key: XXXKEYXXX',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Cache-Control: no-cache',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0',
    'Date: Tue, 26 Jan 2017 21:13:37 GMT'
];


  $ch = curl_init();
  $url = 'https://api.inthegra.strans.teresina.pi.gov.br/v1/signin';

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);                //0 for a get request
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data2);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,100);
//  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);

  curl_close ($ch);
 $token = json_decode($response);
 $auth = $token->token;
 #print $auth;

 #second

 $headers2 = [
    'x-api-key: XXXKEYXXX',
    'x-auth-token:'.$auth,
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Cache-Control: no-cache',
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0',
    'Date: Tue, 26 Jan 2017 21:13:37 GMT'
];

 $ch2 = curl_init();
  $url2 = 'https://api.inthegra.strans.teresina.pi.gov.br/v1/veiculos';
#$header = array('x-api-key' => 'XXXKEYXXX','x-auth-token' => 'XXXTOKENXXX');
 //$header2 = json_encode($header);

curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers2);

#curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('x-api-key' => 'XXXKEYXXX','x-auth-token' => 'XXXTOKENXXX'));
  curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_URL,$url2);
  #curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 0);                //0 for a get request
 curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);

  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "x-auth-token : XXXTOKENXXX");
  //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data2);
  curl_setopt($ch2,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,100);
//  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 100);
  $response2 = curl_exec($ch2);

  curl_close ($ch2);

 //$string = json_decode($response2, TRUE);

//print_r($string[0]);

$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($response2, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key";
    } else {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
}



?>
```

RESPONSE:

```
0LinhaCodigoLinha => 0402 Denomicao => VILA BANDEIRANTE-PLANALTO ININGA FREI SERAFIM Origem => VILA BANDEIRANTE Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 02154 Lat => -5.06117700 Long => -42.77218800 Hora => 16:27:33 1CodigoVeiculo => 02196 Lat => -5.03798000 Long => -42.74236700 Hora => 16:27:05 1LinhaCodigoLinha => 0404 Denomicao => VILA BANDEIRANTE DOM SEVERINO Origem => VILA BANDEIRANTE Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 02128 Lat => -5.05477700 Long => -42.74862200 Hora => 16:26:32 2LinhaCodigoLinha => 0360 Denomicao => DIAMETRAL MOCAMBINHO-PROMORAR Origem => MOCAMBINHO Retorno => PROMORAR Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04366 Lat => -5.07271500 Long => -42.81339000 Hora => 16:28:14 1CodigoVeiculo => 04402 Lat => -5.02577700 Long => -42.81431700 Hora => 16:28:05 2CodigoVeiculo => 04415 Lat => -5.02807000 Long => -42.81902700 Hora => 16:28:13 3CodigoVeiculo => 04435 Lat => -5.09851300 Long => -42.80265500 Hora => 16:28:08 4CodigoVeiculo => 04443 Lat => -5.02804200 Long => -42.81872500 Hora => 16:28:17 3LinhaCodigoLinha => 0615 Denomicao => HD-SACY SHOPPING VIA MIGUEL ROSA Origem => SACY Retorno => SHOPPING Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04314 Lat => -5.11280500 Long => -42.80174000 Hora => 16:28:37 1CodigoVeiculo => 04385 Lat => -5.11925500 Long => -42.80264000 Hora => 16:28:11 2CodigoVeiculo => 04397 Lat => -5.13750300 Long => -42.80710000 Hora => 16:28:16 3CodigoVeiculo => 04431 Lat => -5.11814300 Long => -42.80038300 Hora => 16:27:55 4LinhaCodigoLinha => 0617 Denomicao => HD-PLA. BELA VISTA SHOPPING VIA M. Origem => PL. BELA VISTA Retorno => SHOPPING Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04374 Lat => -5.08595500 Long => -42.79080700 Hora => 16:27:57 5LinhaCodigoLinha => 0709 Denomicao => SACY BARAO Origem => SACY Retorno => PCA. SARAIVA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04323 Lat => -5.09994300 Long => -42.81172200 Hora => 16:28:09 6LinhaCodigoLinha => 0619 Denomicao => JARDIM-EUROPA TODOS OS SANTOS MIGUEL ROSA Origem => JARDIM EUROPA Retorno => PCA. JOAO LUIZ Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03228 Lat => -5.09954500 Long => -42.73229000 Hora => 16:27:53 7LinhaCodigoLinha => 0801 Denomicao => SANTA FE PEDRO FREITAS Origem => CJ. SANTA FE Retorno => PCA. SARAIVA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04357 Lat => -5.09565200 Long => -42.81390200 Hora => 16:28:09 8LinhaCodigoLinha => 0802 Denomicao => SANTA FE MARANHAO VIA SANTO ANTONIO Origem => CJ. SANTA FE Retorno => PCA. SARAIVA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04306 Lat => -5.11415300 Long => -42.81447300 Hora => 16:27:52 1CodigoVeiculo => 04381 Lat => -5.16114500 Long => -42.78276800 Hora => 16:28:19 2CodigoVeiculo => 04411 Lat => -5.15410700 Long => -42.79080200 Hora => 16:28:12 9LinhaCodigoLinha => 0401 Denomicao => UNIVERSIDADE Origem => COL. AGRICOLA Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 02776 Lat => -5.04754300 Long => -42.78410500 Hora => 16:28:04 10LinhaCodigoLinha => 0505 Denomicao => REDONDA-DIRCEU I JOAO XXIII Origem => REDONDA Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03067 Lat => -5.08748000 Long => -42.80548000 Hora => 16:28:12 1CodigoVeiculo => 03069 Lat => -5.09497500 Long => -42.80929200 Hora => 16:27:54 2CodigoVeiculo => 03216 Lat => -5.10353300 Long => -42.75176300 Hora => 16:28:26 3CodigoVeiculo => 03257 Lat => -5.08462200 Long => -42.79924000 Hora => 16:27:09 11LinhaCodigoLinha => 0506 Denomicao => SAO PAULO RENASCENCA I JOAO XXIII Origem => SAO PAULO Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03064 Lat => -5.10472800 Long => -42.75285200 Hora => 16:28:13 1CodigoVeiculo => 03070 Lat => -5.11291200 Long => -42.74164800 Hora => 16:28:12 12LinhaCodigoLinha => 0507 Denomicao => JARDIM EUROPA-BOM PRINCIPIO J. XXIII Origem => JARDIM EUROPA Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03068 Lat => -5.10521800 Long => -42.72679500 Hora => 16:28:13 1CodigoVeiculo => 03446 Lat => -5.10467000 Long => -42.75354500 Hora => 16:27:55 2CodigoVeiculo => 03453 Lat => -5.09173200 Long => -42.81083300 Hora => 16:28:21 13LinhaCodigoLinha => 0509 Denomicao => HD-PARQUE JUREMA-SHOPPING Origem => PARQUE JUREMA Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03221 Lat => -5.11011800 Long => -42.75002000 Hora => 16:28:07 1CodigoVeiculo => 03239 Lat => -5.08985200 Long => -42.76103500 Hora => 16:28:13 14LinhaCodigoLinha => 0510 Denomicao => PARQUE JUREMA-DIRCEU II JOAO XXIII Origem => PARQUE JUREMA Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03198 Lat => -5.08169800 Long => -42.77216300 Hora => 16:28:15 1CodigoVeiculo => 03209 Lat => -5.09656300 Long => -42.81632000 Hora => 16:28:10 2CodigoVeiculo => 03254 Lat => -5.10942300 Long => -42.75004600 Hora => 16:27:15 15LinhaCodigoLinha => 0515 Denomicao => HD-SAO PAULO SHOPPING VIA SAO JOAO Origem => SAO PAULO Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03207 Lat => -5.09366000 Long => -42.76233200 Hora => 16:28:02 16LinhaCodigoLinha => 0611 Denomicao => ALTO DA RESSUREICAO PONTE WALL FERRAZ Origem => A. RESSUREICAO Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03148 Lat => -5.08945200 Long => -42.77684500 Hora => 16:28:14 17LinhaCodigoLinha => 0614 Denomicao => SANTA FE MIGUEL ROSA VIA SHOPPING Origem => CJ. SANTA FE Retorno => SHOPPING Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04324 Lat => -5.15393200 Long => -42.79710700 Hora => 16:28:04 18LinhaCodigoLinha => 0702 Denomicao => SAO PAULO-RENASCENCA I E III BARAO Origem => SAO PAULO Retorno => PCA. SARAIVA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03240 Lat => -5.11393500 Long => -42.80537000 Hora => 16:28:12 19LinhaCodigoLinha => 0101 Denomicao => STA. MARIA DA CODIPI PQ. ALVORADA Origem => SANTA MARIA Retorno => LIZAN. NOGUEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01046 Lat => -5.05671500 Long => -42.83146300 Hora => 16:28:09 20LinhaCodigoLinha => 0104 Denomicao => SANTA MARIA SHOPPING VIA PQ. ALVORADA Origem => SANTA MARIA Retorno => SHOPPING Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01081 Lat => -5.08121300 Long => -42.81009700 Hora => 16:28:18 1CodigoVeiculo => 01082 Lat => -5.08079500 Long => -42.81570200 Hora => 16:28:01 2CodigoVeiculo => 01087 Lat => -4.99118000 Long => -42.84470700 Hora => 16:28:17 21LinhaCodigoLinha => 0105 Denomicao => HD-SANTA MARIA-MONTE VERDE PQ ALVORADA Origem => SANTA MARIA Retorno => LIZAN. NOGUEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01344 Lat => -4.98822800 Long => -42.81105500 Hora => 16:27:34 1CodigoVeiculo => 01363 Lat => -5.04831800 Long => -42.82542800 Hora => 16:27:55 2CodigoVeiculo => 01379 Lat => -4.98237200 Long => -42.81401700 Hora => 16:27:53 3CodigoVeiculo => 01386 Lat => -5.01601700 Long => -42.83047000 Hora => 16:28:05 22LinhaCodigoLinha => 0106 Denomicao => HD-SANTA MARIA-VASSOURAS PQ. ALVORADA Origem => SANTA MARIA Retorno => LIZAN. NOGUEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01069 Lat => -5.06699500 Long => -42.82806000 Hora => 16:28:19 23LinhaCodigoLinha => 0501 Denomicao => ANITA FERRAZ VIA CONJUNTO Origem => ANITA FERRAZ Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 02180 Lat => -5.09107300 Long => -42.81935200 Hora => 16:27:48 1CodigoVeiculo => 02202 Lat => -5.01412000 Long => -42.77463700 Hora => 16:27:35 24LinhaCodigoLinha => 0508 Denomicao => PQ. ITARARE-B. ESPERANCA SAO JOAO Origem => PQ. PROGRESSO Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03205 Lat => -5.08010800 Long => -42.78907300 Hora => 16:28:21 1CodigoVeiculo => 03220 Lat => -5.09143500 Long => -42.76129500 Hora => 16:28:11 25LinhaCodigoLinha => 0517 Denomicao => HD-PARQUE ITARARE SHOPPING VIA SAO Origem => RES. FREI DAMIAO Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03217 Lat => -5.09030000 Long => -42.81807500 Hora => 16:28:19 1CodigoVeiculo => 03405 Lat => -5.08564000 Long => -42.77754200 Hora => 16:28:18 26LinhaCodigoLinha => 0103 Denomicao => MOCAMBINHO-ALTO ALEGRE MATADOURO Origem => MOCAMBINHO Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01076 Lat => -5.09035200 Long => -42.82007000 Hora => 16:28:19 27LinhaCodigoLinha => 0206 Denomicao => BUENOS AIRES AEROPORTO Origem => BUENOS AIRES Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01336 Lat => -5.09069500 Long => -42.81874000 Hora => 16:28:12 1CodigoVeiculo => 01346 Lat => -5.04226800 Long => -42.80851700 Hora => 16:27:53 2CodigoVeiculo => 01381 Lat => -5.03281000 Long => -42.80607700 Hora => 16:27:54 28LinhaCodigoLinha => 0301 Denomicao => MOCAMBINHO DUQUE DE CAXIAS Origem => MOCAMBINHO Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01067 Lat => -5.02797700 Long => -42.81851200 Hora => 16:28:07 1CodigoVeiculo => 01080 Lat => -5.03137000 Long => -42.81069300 Hora => 16:28:22 2CodigoVeiculo => 01090 Lat => -5.09060800 Long => -42.81866000 Hora => 16:28:11 3CodigoVeiculo => 01094 Lat => -5.06772700 Long => -42.81214500 Hora => 16:28:03 29LinhaCodigoLinha => 0302 Denomicao => MOCAMBINHO ASSEMBLEIA VIA SHOPPING Origem => MOCAMBINHO Retorno => PCA. JOAO LUIZ Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01408 Lat => -5.08679500 Long => -42.81143000 Hora => 16:27:31 30LinhaCodigoLinha => 0303 Denomicao => SANTA SOFIA AV. JOSE S. SILVA Origem => SANTA SOFIA Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01074 Lat => -5.09092800 Long => -42.81925700 Hora => 16:28:12 1CodigoVeiculo => 01405 Lat => -5.03513300 Long => -42.81621600 Hora => 16:26:17 31LinhaCodigoLinha => 0304 Denomicao => BUENOS AIRES/ALAMEDA PARNAIBA Origem => BUENOS AIRES Retorno => LIZAN. NOGUEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01342 Lat => -5.09155000 Long => -42.81930700 Hora => 16:28:08 1CodigoVeiculo => 01375 Lat => -5.04723200 Long => -42.81037300 Hora => 16:28:09 32LinhaCodigoLinha => 0607 Denomicao => PROMORAR MIGUEL ROSA Origem => TERMINAL 1 Retorno => TERMINAL 2 Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04328 Lat => -5.08903000 Long => -42.81309500 Hora => 16:28:09 1CodigoVeiculo => 04425 Lat => -5.11679500 Long => -42.79856200 Hora => 16:28:20 33LinhaCodigoLinha => 0618 Denomicao => HD-PROMORAR SHOPPING VIA MIGUEL ROSA Origem => PROMORAR Retorno => SHOPPING Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04414 Lat => -5.08889800 Long => -42.81313300 Hora => 16:28:13 34LinhaCodigoLinha => 0004 Denomicao => I.A.P.C/CRISTO REI Origem => CONJ. J. E. FALCAO Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03065 Lat => -5.09773500 Long => -42.78905000 Hora => 16:28:14 35LinhaCodigoLinha => 0327 Denomicao => RODOVIARIA CIRCULAR 2 Origem => TERMINAL RODOVIARIO Retorno => BAL. COCA-COLA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03445 Lat => -5.10776800 Long => -42.75251300 Hora => 16:27:37 1CodigoVeiculo => 03457 Lat => -5.08780200 Long => -42.77156000 Hora => 16:27:44 2CodigoVeiculo => 03460 Lat => -5.04740000 Long => -42.81298700 Hora => 16:27:58 36LinhaCodigoLinha => 0603 Denomicao => PARQUE JUREMA-DIRCEU II M. ROSA Origem => PARQUE JUREMA Retorno => PARQUE JUREMA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03416 Lat => -5.08844200 Long => -42.80672000 Hora => 16:27:37 37LinhaCodigoLinha => 0610 Denomicao => TRES ANDARES-C. NOVA MONTE CASTELO Origem => TRES ANDARES Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 02503 Lat => -5.10740500 Long => -42.78406700 Hora => 16:27:47 1CodigoVeiculo => 02780 Lat => -5.10077700 Long => -42.79911700 Hora => 16:28:19 38LinhaCodigoLinha => 0612 Denomicao => REDENCAO CASA MATER Origem => REDENCAO Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03403 Lat => -5.09631200 Long => -42.81320800 Hora => 16:27:46 1CodigoVeiculo => 03433 Lat => -5.11847200 Long => -42.79259700 Hora => 16:27:54 2CodigoVeiculo => 03447 Lat => -5.09677700 Long => -42.78907800 Hora => 16:27:47 39LinhaCodigoLinha => 0710 Denomicao => ALTO DA RESSUREICAO/BARAO Origem => A. RESSUREICAO Retorno => PCA. SARAIVA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03421 Lat => -5.10534800 Long => -42.76134200 Hora => 16:27:53 1CodigoVeiculo => 03422 Lat => -5.11466000 Long => -42.79351700 Hora => 16:27:28 2CodigoVeiculo => 03450 Lat => -5.08853200 Long => -42.73532500 Hora => 16:27:56 40LinhaCodigoLinha => 0723 Denomicao => RODOVIARIA CIRCULAR I Origem => TERMINAL RODOVIARIO Retorno => BAL. COCA-COLA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04318 Lat => -5.13406800 Long => -42.78449700 Hora => 16:27:46 1CodigoVeiculo => 04421 Lat => -5.05324500 Long => -42.78640000 Hora => 16:28:15 41LinhaCodigoLinha => 0102 Denomicao => POTY VELHO F. SERAFIM VIA ACARAPE Origem => POTY VELHO Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01048 Lat => -5.08889200 Long => -42.81555000 Hora => 16:28:18 42LinhaCodigoLinha => 0107 Denomicao => HD-ANITA FERRAZ-NOVA TERESINA P. VE Origem => ANITA FERRAZ Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01330 Lat => -5.00716500 Long => -42.77346000 Hora => 16:28:18 43LinhaCodigoLinha => 0170 Denomicao => DIAMETRAL POTY VELHO-PL. BELA VISTA Origem => POTY VELHO Retorno => PL. BELA VISTA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04304 Lat => -5.14306800 Long => -42.78715300 Hora => 16:28:09 1CodigoVeiculo => 04363 Lat => -5.14336800 Long => -42.78811800 Hora => 16:27:53 2CodigoVeiculo => 04390 Lat => -5.09355700 Long => -42.81826200 Hora => 16:28:32 44LinhaCodigoLinha => 0201 Denomicao => SANTA MARIA DA CODIPI FREI SERAFIM Origem => SANTA MARIA Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01052 Lat => -4.98687200 Long => -42.81568800 Hora => 16:28:18 45LinhaCodigoLinha => 0202 Denomicao => HD-SANTA MARIA-MONTE VERDE-FREI SERAFIM Origem => SANTA MARIA Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01371 Lat => -5.07569300 Long => -42.81429300 Hora => 16:27:51 1CodigoVeiculo => 01400 Lat => -4.98423800 Long => -42.81415200 Hora => 16:27:47 46LinhaCodigoLinha => 0204 Denomicao => HD-SANTA MARIA-VASSOURAS FREI SERAFIM Origem => SANTA MARIA Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01054 Lat => -5.03384700 Long => -42.82880500 Hora => 16:28:12 1CodigoVeiculo => 01084 Lat => -5.08767300 Long => -42.80996800 Hora => 16:28:14 47LinhaCodigoLinha => 0270 Denomicao => DIAMETRAL MOCAMBINHO-PORTO ALEGRE Origem => MOCAMBINHO Retorno => PORTO ALEGRE Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04320 Lat => -5.02811700 Long => -42.81891000 Hora => 16:28:15 1CodigoVeiculo => 04337 Lat => -5.19232700 Long => -42.73756200 Hora => 16:28:08 2CodigoVeiculo => 04423 Lat => -5.02801300 Long => -42.81868800 Hora => 16:28:16 3CodigoVeiculo => 04429 Lat => -5.07477200 Long => -42.82092700 Hora => 16:28:20 48LinhaCodigoLinha => 0503 Denomicao => V BANDEIRANTES-SATELITE S. CRISTOVAO Origem => VILA BANDEIRANTE Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 02551 Lat => -5.08452200 Long => -42.79927700 Hora => 16:28:24 1CodigoVeiculo => 02782 Lat => -5.09116300 Long => -42.81108500 Hora => 16:27:48 49LinhaCodigoLinha => 0504 Denomicao => REDONDA-ALTO DA RESSUREICAO JOAO XXIII Origem => A. RESSUREICAO Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03037 Lat => -5.08092500 Long => -42.78054500 Hora => 16:28:28 50LinhaCodigoLinha => 0512 Denomicao => VILA BANDEIRANTES SAO CRISTOVAO Origem => VILA BANDEIRANTE Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 02788 Lat => -5.08009300 Long => -42.78934200 Hora => 16:28:18 51LinhaCodigoLinha => 0513 Denomicao => PLANALTO URUGUAI SAO CRISTOVAO Origem => PLAN. URUGUAI Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 02559 Lat => -5.08459300 Long => -42.79941500 Hora => 16:27:43 52LinhaCodigoLinha => 0522 Denomicao => HD-VALE DO GAVIAO-ARVORES VERDE VIA FAET Origem => PLAN. URUGUAI Retorno => AV MARANHAO Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 02188 Lat => -5.08536800 Long => -42.80037800 Hora => 16:27:47 1CodigoVeiculo => 02200 Lat => -5.06560200 Long => -42.74903300 Hora => 16:28:03 53LinhaCodigoLinha => 0621 Denomicao => HD-IRMA DULCE-ANGELIM MIGUEL ROSA Origem => PORTO ALEGRE Retorno => PCA. JOAO LUIZ Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04329 Lat => -5.08840200 Long => -42.80631000 Hora => 16:28:14 1CodigoVeiculo => 04341 Lat => -5.19305700 Long => -42.76880200 Hora => 16:28:16 2CodigoVeiculo => 04358 Lat => -5.11733500 Long => -42.79899200 Hora => 16:15:55 3CodigoVeiculo => 04404 Lat => -5.19061300 Long => -42.75999700 Hora => 16:28:21 54LinhaCodigoLinha => 0706 Denomicao => HD-IRMA DULCE-BARAO Origem => PORTO ALEGRE Retorno => PCA. SARAIVA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04455 Lat => -5.19326700 Long => -42.76930500 Hora => 16:28:13 55LinhaCodigoLinha => 0711 Denomicao => VILA SAO FRANCISCO-PROMORAR BARAO Origem => CONJ. VAMOS VER Retorno => PCA. SARAIVA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04322 Lat => -5.14612000 Long => -42.78536300 Hora => 16:28:11 1CodigoVeiculo => 04413 Lat => -5.14372300 Long => -42.77781800 Hora => 15:52:10 56LinhaCodigoLinha => 0713 Denomicao => CERAMICA CIL BARAO Origem => CERAMICA CIL Retorno => PCA. SARAIVA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04437 Lat => -5.12310300 Long => -42.80045000 Hora => 16:28:20 57LinhaCodigoLinha => 0365 Denomicao => UNIVERSIDADE CIRCULAR 2 VIA SHOPPING Origem => UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 02186 Lat => -5.08110800 Long => -42.77877200 Hora => 16:27:35 1CodigoVeiculo => 02784 Lat => -5.10175000 Long => -42.81299200 Hora => 16:28:14 58LinhaCodigoLinha => 0563 Denomicao => UNIVERSIDADE CIRCULAR I VIA SHOPPING Origem => UNIVERSIDADE FEDERAL Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01078 Lat => -5.09889300 Long => -42.78933300 Hora => 16:28:18 1CodigoVeiculo => 01132 Lat => -5.06346200 Long => -42.78446300 Hora => 16:26:17 2CodigoVeiculo => 01176 Lat => -5.08481500 Long => -42.78793700 Hora => 16:28:11 59LinhaCodigoLinha => 0703 Denomicao => PARQUE JUREMA DIRCEU II BARAO Origem => PARQUE JUREMA Retorno => PCA. SARAIVA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03424 Lat => -5.11532300 Long => -42.75073000 Hora => 16:27:55 1CodigoVeiculo => 03441 Lat => -5.09717500 Long => -42.81148500 Hora => 16:28:09 60LinhaCodigoLinha => 0601 Denomicao => REDONDA-DIRCEU I MIGUEL ROSA Origem => REDONDA Retorno => PCA. JOAO LUIZ Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03251 Lat => -5.09933000 Long => -42.73880800 Hora => 16:27:35 61LinhaCodigoLinha => 0602 Denomicao => SAO PAULO-RENASCENCA I M. ROSA Origem => SAO PAULO Retorno => PCA. JOAO LUIZ Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03143 Lat => -5.11350700 Long => -42.73781200 Hora => 16:28:11 1CodigoVeiculo => 03211 Lat => -5.10954300 Long => -42.76972300 Hora => 16:28:09 2CodigoVeiculo => 03215 Lat => -5.09618500 Long => -42.80276300 Hora => 16:28:09 62LinhaCodigoLinha => 0606 Denomicao => PORTO ALEGRE-PARQUE PIAUI M. ROSA Origem => VILA DA GLORIA Retorno => PCA. JOAO LUIZ Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04305 Lat => -5.08918500 Long => -42.80516500 Hora => 16:28:18 1CodigoVeiculo => 04334 Lat => -5.11566700 Long => -42.79928700 Hora => 16:28:18 63LinhaCodigoLinha => T0203 Denomicao => BOA VISTA / SHOPPING Origem => CONJ. BOA VISTA Retorno => SHOPPING Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 00198 Lat => -5.10271300 Long => -42.86288500 Hora => 16:27:31 64LinhaCodigoLinha => T0650 Denomicao => RUA 100 / PONTE NOVA Origem => RUA 100 Retorno => PRACA SARAIVA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 00138 Lat => -5.12018200 Long => -42.83363800 Hora => 16:28:14 1CodigoVeiculo => 00183 Lat => -5.11579000 Long => -42.83445800 Hora => 16:28:18 2CodigoVeiculo => 00194 Lat => -5.11238300 Long => -42.84723800 Hora => 16:28:11 65LinhaCodigoLinha => T1102 Denomicao => PARQUE ALVORADA / PONTE VELHA Origem => PARQUE ALVORADA Retorno => PRACA DA BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 00144 Lat => -5.10476000 Long => -42.82247800 Hora => 16:28:20 66LinhaCodigoLinha => 0108 Denomicao => SANTA MARIA VASSOURA SHOPPING VIA MAFRENSE Origem => TERMINAL SANTA MARIA DA CODIPI Retorno => TERESINA SHOPPING Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01378 Lat => -5.08606700 Long => -42.79068700 Hora => 16:28:14 67LinhaCodigoLinha => 0623 Denomicao => HD-MARIO COVAS-DIGNIDADE M ROSA Origem => RES MARIO COVAS Retorno => PCA. JOAO LUIZ Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04353 Lat => -5.11625800 Long => -42.79888800 Hora => 16:28:21 1CodigoVeiculo => 04356 Lat => -5.16962200 Long => -42.78976000 Hora => 16:28:11 2CodigoVeiculo => 04396 Lat => -5.13656800 Long => -42.79509000 Hora => 16:28:16 68LinhaCodigoLinha => 0714 Denomicao => HD-MARIO COVAS-DIGNIDADE BARAO Origem => RES MARIO COVAS Retorno => PCA. SARAIVA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04321 Lat => -5.14478800 Long => -42.79370200 Hora => 16:28:22 69LinhaCodigoLinha => 0715 Denomicao => TERESINA SUL-PALITOLANDIA-BARAO Origem => VL TIRADENTES Retorno => PCA. SARAIVA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04307 Lat => -5.09440800 Long => -42.81449500 Hora => 16:28:15 70LinhaCodigoLinha => 0521 Denomicao => NOVA TERESINA SAO CRISTOVAO Origem => NOVA TERESINA Retorno => AV MARANHAO Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 02754 Lat => -5.09501700 Long => -42.80975200 Hora => 16:28:18 1CodigoVeiculo => 02778 Lat => -5.01003500 Long => -42.78634000 Hora => 16:28:07 71LinhaCodigoLinha => 0100 Denomicao => REDONDA/SHOPPING VIA SÃO JOÃO Origem => REDONDA Retorno => PCA. JOAO LUIZ Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 03208 Lat => -5.10326000 Long => -42.75556000 Hora => 16:28:21 72LinhaCodigoLinha => 0245 Denomicao => VALE DO GAVIAO / PLANALTO URUGUAI Origem => PLAN. URUGUAI Retorno => SHOPPING Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 02757 Lat => -5.09031000 Long => -42.81802000 Hora => 16:28:11 1CodigoVeiculo => 02759 Lat => -5.05116800 Long => -42.74130800 Hora => 16:28:14 2CodigoVeiculo => 02760 Lat => -5.02286500 Long => -42.74269000 Hora => 16:28:16 73LinhaCodigoLinha => 0901 Denomicao => IRMA DULCE / ESPLANADA / SHOPPING / M.ROSA Origem => TERMINAL 1 Retorno => TERMINAL 2 Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04331 Lat => -5.19326700 Long => -42.79389200 Hora => 16:27:40 74LinhaCodigoLinha => 0688 Denomicao => OPCIONAL - VILA SAO FRANCISCO MIGUEL ROSA Origem => CONJ. VAMOS VER Retorno => PCA. JOAO LUIZ Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04370 Lat => -5.11176800 Long => -42.80284300 Hora => 16:28:22 75LinhaCodigoLinha => 716 Denomicao => TERESINA SUL-PALITOLANDIA-BR - AV. BARAO Origem => TERMINAL 1 Retorno => TERMINAL 2 Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 04368 Lat => -5.18480300 Long => -42.76296700 Hora => 16:28:11 76LinhaCodigoLinha => 0109 Denomicao => SANTA MARIA MONTE VERDE/SHOPPING VIA PQ. ALVORADA Origem => JACINTA ANDRADE Retorno => PRACA DA BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01390 Lat => -5.08593500 Long => -42.78699200 Hora => 16:27:53 1CodigoVeiculo => 01398 Lat => -4.98648200 Long => -42.81102700 Hora => 16:27:53 77LinhaCodigoLinha => 0730 Denomicao => UNIVERSIDADE - CENTRO RIO POTY SHOPPING Origem => COL. AGRICOLA Retorno => PCA. BANDEIRA Circular => 1 Veiculos0CodigoVeiculo => 01053 Lat => -5.09507300 Long => -42.80957200 Hora => 16:28:10 1CodigoVeiculo => 01333 Lat => -5.05350500 Long => -42.79091700 Hora => 16:28:04
```

Comment: Could you add var_dump( $response2 ); before the curl_close ($ch2); and post an output here?

Comment: Hi, the output is:

string(27808) "[{"Linha":{"CodigoLinha":"0402","Denomicao":"VILA BANDEIRANTE-PLANALTO ININGA FREI SERAFIM","Origem":"VILA BANDEIRANTE","Retorno":"PCA. BANDEIRA","Circular":true,"Veiculos":[{"CodigoVeiculo":"02154","Lat":"-5.06155800","Long":"-42.77045700","Hora":"19:29:52"}]}}

Are several datasets of this type: (same structure), I did not put all because it did not fit: /

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your response to array and iterate over array elements:

```
$arr_data = json_decode($response2, true);

foreach( $arr_data as $key => $value ) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $sub_value) {
        $lat = $sub_value['Veiculos'][0]['Lat'];
        $long = $sub_value['Veiculos'][0]['Long'];
        echo $lat . ', ' . $long;        
    } 
}
```

Comment: perfect! acception of this answer would be appreciated)